# Photoshop: Move selection without moving pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

How do you move the selection in photoshop (marching ants) without moveing any part(pixels) of the selected layer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In addition to Carl's answer.. you can choose `Select > Transform Selection` from the menu after you've created a selection.

Answer (score 13):

By (re-)selecting the selection tool. You will only move pixels if you drag a selection with the move tool (<kbd>V</kbd>) active. When dragging a selection with the selection tool (<kbd>M</kbd>) active, you'll leave the pixels alone.

Answer (score 2):

While dragging out your marquee selection, hold down the spacebar and that should allow you to do as described.

**Note:** Both must be held down at the same time.

Comment: My marquee is already drawn, how can I move it after it has been drawn.

Answer (score 1):

it only can be done with the "new selection" option active,, when you press key M, it will display a bar with some options... select the first one and then you are now able to move the marching ants without moving any pixels

Comment: Please add an image showing the menu you mentioned ...

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the <kbd>W</kbd> key and move the marquee at the same time, works on Photoshop 2019 and 2020